# Upload a html page and css /js files in google site page

Tags: html, web-deployment

I have created a website in a local system. Now I want to upload the same in site.google.com. Since google is not giving the FTP access. Please help me to upload my html pages and css/js files to the sites.google.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have understand your question but:

- create a folder whose include your files.
- call this folder on your local server.
  At this point when you call your local server your files will appear and you will can download them.